# Icons on Titlebar

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, windows-7, titlebar

I just found something really cool and i'm surprised i didn't really notice it sooner. Have you ever seen WordPad running on Windows 7? If you have, you'll notice that on the top-left of the window's titlebar are a few icons (save, undo/redo). On the actual titlebar itself! How cool is that? I was wondering how i would implement that feature into my own programs but don't know where to start. I went to MSDN and then got lost because i wasn't sure of what to actually look for... Can somebody please help me?

If you would like a piccture of what i'm talking about i can try and upload a pic somewhere like maybe photobucket or similar?

Thank you

Jase

Comment: More info about custom window chrome in WinForms here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42460/custom-titlebars-chrome-in-a-winforms-app

Comment: thanks for the link its very interesting however the links on that page are broken lol :P

Comment: +1 anyway, not your fault theyre broken

Answer (score 1):

It is part of the Ribbon ui.  Here is some code from the code project.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/toolbars/WinFormsRibbon.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use a stack of [commands](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) to create a system that supports multiple level undo.