# Codeplex sample browser - what UI technology is it?

Tags: wpf, windows, codeplex

Codeplex has a strange application for downloading and browsing Windows samples, and I have not been able to understand just what it is:

http://1code.codeplex.com/releases/view/64539

When the click-once application above is installed, it creates a single file in the form of a shortcut which contains the following line only:

[http://1code.codeplex.com/releases/clickonce/SampleBrowser.application#SampleBrowser.application, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=48e4844f2d49d017, processorArchitecture=msil](http://1code.codeplex.com/releases/clickonce/SampleBrowser.application#SampleBrowser.application,%20Culture=neutral,%20PublicKeyToken=48e4844f2d49c017,%20processorArchitecture=msil)

Then, when this shortcut is double-clicked, a sort of browser application comes up, but it has no window borders and is very modern looking.  What type of technology is this?  I am including the WPF tag otherwise I am at my wit's end as to what it is.

(Wanted to include an image of the said application here but can't seem to upload an image as I am getting the following error: "Failed to upload image; imgur is rejecting the request")  Here's a link to that image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8QqL.jpg

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initial part about the odd link is simply a click-once application.  The rest of the application is hidden away somewhere in your user directory.

The "browser" is simply a window which has had its chrome modified.  Could be pretty much any technology.  A couple examples in [winForms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42460/custom-titlebars-chrome-in-a-winforms-app) and [wpf](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsdk/archive/2008/09/08/custom-window-chrome-in-wpf.aspx).

As a caution, if doing a custom chrome in wpf don't use the `AllowTransparency="True"` if you want your comboboxes and such to work properly on XP.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "chrome" and "custom chrome" - are these the borders and such?

Comment: @Sabuncu go look at the examples I linked.