# How to add window extentions similar to the skype productivity tools for skype?

Tags: c#, user-interface, webex

All,

If you install the Webex productivity tools and have skype installed it adds a window decoration from where you can click a button and it will automatically paste into the conversation box a new webex conference link.

I would like to do something similar for my application, but where to start with adding the window decoration? Is there a standard API for this sort of thing?

Any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you basically want to do is to 'Draw custom controls' in the Windows **Non-Client** area. This is also sometimes called the 'Chrome' of the Window.

If you want to do this in your own application, this SO question answers many of the options available: [Custom titlebars/chrome in a WinForms app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42460/custom-titlebars-chrome-in-a-winforms-app)

The code for the main article cited from http://geekswithblogs.net/kobush/articles/CustomBorderForms.aspx is availble at http://customerborderform.codeplex.com/

If you want to add your custom controls to other applications, then you will need to hook into those applications their **WndProc**. In order to achieve that, you will need to inject your dll into that application (see http://www.codingthewheel.com/archives/how-to-inject-a-managed-assembly-dll and http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4610/Three-Ways-to-Inject-Your-Code-into-Another-Proces#section_1) and then hook into the WndProc again.

Comment: Thank you for pulling that lot together, if I'd known what to search for you wouldn't have got the bounty though.

Thanks again.

Comment: No worries, I know the feeling; Google is your friend... if you know what to Google for. Happens to me all the time ;-) Though when I needed this info Google 'Chrome' did not exist yet. The search was a lot easier then. I just had to look at/convert a lot of C/C++ samples.